# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError Could not process parameters

Tags: python, mysql

I was working on MYSQL in Python. I have a class, in this class I have a static function and I have a function in it.
my aim is a gender query and i will give this information via function. When it does a few other different operations, it succeeds, but the external information operations fail. can you help me ?

I tried other solutions on Stackoverflow to solve this. For example, the simplest;
values = (gender,)

```
class Student():
     .
     .
     .
    
     @staticmethod 
     def query(islem):
         .
         .
         .
        def gender(gender):
        sql = "SELECT * ISIM,SOYAD from ogrencilisteleri where GENDER = %s "
        values = (gender)
        Student.mycursor.execute(sql,gender)
```

Comment: sql = "SELECT * NAME,SURNAME from studentlist where GENDER = %s "

Comment: Values should be a tuple or a list, so change it with `values = (gender,)`

Comment: I tired this. Its didnt working

Comment: Your query is wrong, it should be `SELECT * FROM` or `SELECT ISIM, SOYAD FROM` but you cannot use * and the name of columns without a `,` in the same query